# CentOS8 に MySQL8.0 をインストールする際 yum install -y mysql-community-server でエラーが出る

Tags: mysql, centos

仮想環境 (VirtualBox) 上の CentOS8 に MySQL8.0 をインストールしたいのですが、エラーが表示されてしまいます。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
yum install -y mysql-community-server
```

**表示されたメッセージ:**

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:04 ago on Thu 22 Oct 2020 09:01:11 AM UTC.
All matches were filtered out by modular filtering for argument: mysql-community-server

Error: Unable to find a match: mysql-community-server
```

そのひとつ前の操作

```
sudo yum localinstall http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm
```

は正常に動作し、

```
Installed:
  mysql-community-release-el8-l.noarch
    
Complete!
```

と表示されました。

**確認したこと**
・[vagrant@localhost yum.repos.d] で実行しています
・この場所で `ls` とすると `mysql-community.repo` はちゃんと存在しています
・再起動してもダメでした

**環境**
OS: CentOS 8 (202008.16.0)
仮想環境：VirtualBox (Vagrantを用いて操作)

**参考記事**
[CentOS 7にMySQLをインストールして初期設定するまで - Qiita](https://qiita.com/nooboolean/items/7efc5c35b2e95637d8c1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

蛇足ですが、CentOS 8 からは `yum` の代わりに `dnf` コマンドでパッケージを管理します。
yum も一応は継続して使えるはずですが、早めに慣れておきましょう。

---

まずは `sudo dnf check-update` でパッケージ情報を更新してから `sudo dnf search mysql-community-server` でパッケージ名が検索にヒットするか確認してみましょう。

これでもだめな場合、CentOS 8 では以下の追加手順が事前に必要かもしれません。

[CensOS8にMySQLを入れてみる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/nunemoga/items/79ea64d30ee3fa2d8b4f#122-mysql%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E7%84%A1%E5%8A%B9%E5%8C%96)

> #### MySQLのモジュールストリームの無効化
>
> mysql のモジュールストリームを無効化します。
> これを実施しないと、mysql-community-*-debuginfo パッケージしか表示されません。
>
> ```
> $ sudo dnf -y module disable mysql
> ```

モジュールストリームの無効化を行った後で、改めてパッケージ名の検索 (ヒットするか)、インストールを試してみてください。

```
$ sudo dnf search mysql-community-server
$ sudo dnf -y install mysql-community-server
```